# How can I get the vice C64 (commodore 64) emulator to work

Tags: games, emulation

I want to play games on the vice emulator on Ubuntu 14.04. I have never managed to get vice working in Ubuntu. What are the steps needed to achieve this?

Comment: What's Vice C64?

Comment: It's a commodore 64 emulator. There is a a linux version but I don't know how to get it working. I have now discovered you can sudo apt-get install wine and then download the windows version and use it with wine

Comment: See this for an update: https://askubuntu.com/a/1062151/29097 and improved method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### update --- there is a new release now, 3.3, and as 3.2, works great.

I managed to compile it with trial-and-errors adding the following libraries:

```
sudo apt install xa65 libreadline-dev libxaw7-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev libpulse-dev
```

and compiled with

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

...and it seems to work (the lib hack is not needed anymore). Seems a quite live project!

#### Original content:

You can compile the native version pretty easily (well...). Tested with version 2.4.
(compact instructions --- tell me if you need more details).

1) download the last version from http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/

2) unpack it where you want

```
tar xvzf vice-3.1.tar.gz
cd vice-3.1
```

3) install required dev libraries:

```
sudo apt install build-essential  libvte-dev libasound2-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgnome2-dev byacc flex
```

4) configure, compile and install (it will go in `/usr/local/`). On my netbook, I have a coffee after the "make"...

```
./configure --enable-gnomeui
make
sudo make install
```

5) if you machine is 64 bit, do the following (as root)

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s ../lib64/vice .
```

(this is probably a bug; the emulator will search the ROMS in /usr/local/lib even if the installation is a 64 bit one and the `install` program will put the libraries under /usr/local/lib64/)

6) type `x64` and Enjoy! (this thing evokes a tear... my first computer ever was a C64. If only I did not lose my discs...)

[image: vice x64 running]

Comment: thanks @Rmano, now I can finally play mission impossible on ubuntu. just a quick question: is it possible to set fullscreen mode? I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Fullscreen does not work for me either. It produce a borderless window, but does not scale to fit the monitor. I think is by design; really the emulator maps 4 (2x2) real pixels to each pixel of the C64. But you can ask the upstream forums...

Comment: This still works with Ubuntu 14.04, playing last ninja and it works great, fullscreen doesn't work for me either.

Comment: How do you actually run VICE after the `sudo make install` command?

Comment: in the terminal type x64

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.10 with vice-3.1 you need  `sudo apt install byacc flex` before you `configure`

Comment: I like this emulator as it produces the sound of the 1541 Floppy Drive.  Definitely a tear is shedding!  =)  Thank you!

Comment: I also had to `sudo apt install xa65` for vice-3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @DavidJ yes --- it's in the updated first line of the message. Thanks!

Comment: `libgnome2-dev` is not found in Ubuntu 20.04, is this really needed? maybe build it from source then too? or get it from Debian stretch [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libgnome2-dev), and [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libgnome-2-0/download) also needed then would be `libbonobo2-0`, `libgnomevfs2-0`, liborbit-2-0` and `libgnome2-common` ?

Comment: @rubo77 I have no time to check here, but in https://vice-emu.sourceforge.io/NEWS it seems that the new version (3.4) is on Gtk3... so it's a matter of downloading and trying to compile.

Comment: without `libgnome2-dev` I get the error `configure: error: invalid option: --enable-gnomeui` on 20.04

Comment: I used this: `apt install xa65 libglew-dev` and then `./configure; make; make install`. The command is now `x64sc` but it seems to work correctly. I am on 18.04 still, can you check it on 20.04? @rubo77

Comment: I get an error `Makefile:1119: vice.txt] Fehler 127` after some making time: https://pastebin.pl/view/bb725dd9 - I tested `apt install xa65 libglew-dev` and then `./configure; make`

Comment: Anyway: on Ubuntu 20.04 there is no need to compile, in the ap repositories is the latest version 3.4: `sudo apt-get install vice` and then start `x64sc`.

Answer (score 6):

To install vice with the default roms, you can

1. Install vice from the system repos

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vice
   ```
2. Install the roms,

   1. Download the source tarball http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/index.html#download and extract it to `/tmp`
   2. Run the following commands to copy over the data files,

      ```
      find /tmp/vice-*/data \
        -mindepth 1 \
        -type d \
        -exec sudo cp -rnv {} /usr/lib/vice/ \;
      ```

now you can use `x64` and `x64sc` to run the bin files.

Comment: Works great!  +1  Full screen no longer has lines in it like when I build from source.

Comment: No need to copy it into the root filesystem. Just copy the folders from the `data` directory of the vice tarball to `~/.config/vice`. Or in the command above, replace `/usr/lib/vice/` by `~/.config/vice`. (You might need to create the folder first: `mkdir -p ~/.config/vice`.)

Comment: @pcworld - this doesn't work with 3.5. A pity, as it would be nice not have to replace the ROMs every time Ubuntu updates. Also, the Vice ROMs folder is now `/usr/share/vice/` and files under /usr/lib/vice are no longer found.

Answer (score 0):

Compile and install went well 1st time on my
fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, however
i found that the C64 had no keyboard response.

This was fixed by copying the x11_sym.vkm and
sdl_sym.vkm files from the source codes data/C64
folder into the installed C64 folder.